# apache 2.4 on windows gives no permission error on forms submit button click

Tags: php, forms, apache, windows-10, cgi

I am testing an HTML forms, for it's cgi feature. a method post, and action with a cgi file name.
all apache config directives have been checked and rechecked, but it's always one of two errors: file not found, or you do not have permission.
The form works, the click work works- partly: the browser shows the errors, and the address bar shows the localhost/cgi filename.

have attached a picture of the httpd.conf - relevant parts. and a hierarchy of directories involved. Apache24 is installed in c:\ and SRVROOT [p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Pel.jpg)oints at that dir: c:/Apache24.
Here are the two errors I extracted from the log files...

please guide me in discovering what the actual problem is?

Comment: give  sufficient privileges(755)  for perl script and test.

Comment: I am on Windows, so the 755 has no meaning... and anyway, I have "full control" for everyone for all the folders and subfolders. Also, I am trying to use php and python as the script interpreter, not perl.